# ios move touch event between two uiscrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I'm building an iOS layout which consists of a `UITableView` and a `UIScrollView`. The `UIScrollView` is inside a table cell of the `UITableView` and can be scrolled both horizontally and vertically. The diagram below shows this situation. If the user begins scrolling down/up on the `UIScrollView` the scrolling event should trigger `setContentOffset` of the table view, and not `setContentOffset` for the scroll view while the top of the scroll view will be on the dotted line (it's constant height). Then a scrolling touch event should trigger `setContentOffset` for the scroll view, not for the table view.

In another case: When the user starts scrolling on the table view, it should trigger `setContentOffset` for the table view, until  the scroll view reaches the dotted line. Then the scroll view should handle `setContentOffset`.

My problem is how to transfer touch events between the table view and the scroll view during one sliding action.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like one of those cases where you want something quite specific and custom. So trying to do something clever with the gesture recognizers won't be enough.

The main problem is that the ways you can control gesture recognizers such as with `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` and `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` only affect the start of the gesture (or for new touches, not ongoing ones), but you want a single ongoing gesture to transition between controlling each view. So for this reason I think you will need to place a large transparent view over your entire screen with a pan gesture recognizer on it and in your handlePan method decide which view you want to adjust and then call `setContentOffset` directly on that view. You can use the translation of the pan recognizer and the existing content offset to calculate the new one. I know this isn't very elegant, but I can't think of another way to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is going to work, but you could try doing something like this:

1. Option

   `self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer = self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer;`
2. Option

   `[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer];`
3. Option

   ```
   [self.tableView.panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
   ```